# Converting HTML with equations pages to docx

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, ms-word, pandoc

I am trying to convert an html document to docx using pandoc.

```
pandoc -s Template.html --mathjax -o Test.docx
```

During the conversion to docx everything goes smooth less the equations.
In the html file the equation look like this:

```
<div class="jp-Cell jp-MarkdownCell jp-Notebook-cell">
<div class="jp-Cell-inputWrapper">
<div class="jp-Collapser jp-InputCollapser jp-Cell-inputCollapser">
</div>
<div class="jp-InputArea jp-Cell-inputArea"><div class="jp-RenderedHTMLCommon jp-RenderedMarkdown jp-MarkdownOutput " data-mime-type="text/markdown">
\begin{equation}
\log_{10}(\mu)={-2.64}+\frac{4437.038}{T-544.391}
\end{equation}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

After running the pandoc command the result in the docx document is:

```
\begin{equation} \log_{10}(\mu)={-2.64}+\frac{4437.038}{T-544.391} \end{equation}
```

Do you have idea how can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters) can help here. The code below looks for div elements with a `data-mime-type="text/markdown"` attribute and, somewhat paradoxically, parses it context as LaTeX. The original div is then replaced with the parse result.

```lua
local stringify = pandoc.utils.stringify
function Div (div)
  if div.attributes['mime-type'] == 'text/markdown' then
    return pandoc.read(stringify(div), 'latex').blocks
  end
end
```

Save the code to a file `parse-math.lua` and let pandoc use it with the `--lua-filter` / `-L` option:

```
pandoc --lua-filter parse-math.lua ...
```

As noted in a comment, this gets slightly more complicated if there are other HTML elements with the `text/markdown` media type. In that case we'll check if the parse result contains *only math*, and keep the original content otherwise.

```lua
local stringify = pandoc.utils.stringify
function Div (div)
  if div.attributes['mime-type'] == 'text/markdown' then
    local result = pandoc.read(stringify(div), 'latex').blocks
    local first = result[1] and result[1].content or {}
    return (#first == 1 and first[1].t == 'Math')
      and result
      or nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my issue with the equations. However, now the tables are not shown in the docx document because their type is also "text/markdown", Is there any way we can skip the tables (code below) in the lua filter?                                                             <div class="jp-InputArea jp-Cell-inputArea"><div class="jp-RenderedHTMLCommon jp-RenderedMarkdown jp-MarkdownOutput " data-mime-type="text/markdown">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<table id="T_ac38c_">

Comment: @RuiCarneiro That's a bit more complicated, but not much. See the updated answer.